# How to display the button in one line after the input tag, which is embedded in a div block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

For nested forms I use gem coocon. 
I have next view

**_poll_item_field.html.erb**

```
.poll_row
  .poll_item
    = f.input :answer, input_html: { class: 'ctrlenter expanding' }, label: false, placeholder: 'Введите вариант ответа'
    = button_tag 'Up', class: 'btn btn-bg', id: 'up_id', type: 'button'
    = button_tag 'Down', type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-bg', id: 'down_id'

    = link_to_remove_association "delete", f, { wrapper_class: 'poll_item' }
```

**Generated html**

```
<div class="poll_item">
      <div class="control-group string required blog_post_poll_poll_items_answer">
        <div class="controls"><input class="string required ctrlenter expanding" display="inline" id="  blog_post_poll_attributes_poll_items_attributes_0_answer" margin="0" name="blog_post[poll_attributes][poll_items_attributes][0][answer]" placeholder="Введите вариант ответа" size="50" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
      <button class="btn btn-bg" display="inline" id="up_id" name="button" type="button">up</button>
      <button class="btn btn-bg" display="inline" id="down_id" name="button" type="button">down</button>
      <input id="blog_post_poll_attributes_poll_items_attributes_0__destroy" name="blog_post[poll_attributes][poll_items_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="#" class="remove_fields dynamic" data-wrapper-class="poll_item">delete</a>
    </div>
```

There is a field for input with class **ctrlenter expanding**, after two buttons "up" and "down" to be added . At the moment, these buttons are displayed after the input field on the next line, and it is necessary that they were in one line in place with input field. What styles I should add in order to realize this?

I added in _layout.sass

```
#up_id, #down_id 
  display: inline-block
```

But dont wotk

Comment: try `display: inline-block   !important `

Comment: i tryed. isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is an angry beast you must wrestle into submission. Fortunately, things became a lot easier once [CSS flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) came into existence. If you want things in a line, simply do

```
.things-in-a-line{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* this is actually the default, but I put it here for clarity reasons */
}
```

And then wrap all of the elements in an element with a `.things-in-a-line` class.

For more information, see [MDN's "Using flexible boxes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)